# Word 2007(2010) Viewer

Tags: microsoft-word, viewer

Does Word Viewer 2007 exists (with new Ribbon interface)?

I ask this because only thing I found so far is Word Viewer 2007 as a Viewer 2003 with compatibility packs (which looks like standad Office 2003), but that doesn't works very well for my documents.

Thanks

Comment: The documents themselves should not be affected by the interface. What exactly is it that `doesn't works very well for my documents`? Can you provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Word 2007 viewer. It can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3657CE88-7CFA-457A-9AEC-F4F827F20CAC&displaylang=en):

> View, print and copy Word documents, even if you don't have Word installed. This download is a **replacement for Word Viewer 2003** and all previous Word Viewer versions

(my bold)

However, I haven't installed it so I can't comment on the UI.

However, it also states:

> The Word Viewer, together with the [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint 2007 File Formats](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=941b3470-3ae9-4aee-8f43-c6bb74cd1466), allows you open Word documents saved in the following formats:
>
> - Word Document (*.docx)

My reading of this is that you need to install the compatibility pack as well to actually read .docx files.

Comment: I have that, and only the first screen of setup indicates that it is 2007 version. After that, regular Word Viewer 2003 is installed (or I messed smth, but don't see what could I do THAT wrong :)

Comment: @Jox - OK, the changes must be in reading `docx` files rather than the UI then.

Comment: Yes, but it's having difficulties opening docx files :(